# Divisivility and Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Hello I have been working in this problem for two days but i can't get the answer, I would appreciate any help or hint.

Let $p$ be prime, $m\ge 1$,     $r \ge 2$   and $(p,r) = 1$.

If there is a simple group $G$ such that $ |G| = p^ {m}r  $, then $ p^ {m}|(r-1)! $

Comment: what do you mean by  $p^m 1$ ?

Comment: Yep so sorry i correct it right now.

Comment: Also, should we be assuming “(p,r) = 1” as well as or instead of “(m,r)=1”?

Comment: Nop .. Sry again .. its (p,r)

Comment: No worries… Fun question, by the way, a bit different from the other Sylow questions I remember seeing before.

Comment: Yes it is .. it's the first time i post here! Thank you for being patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ and let $G$ act on $G/P$ by left multiplication: $p\cdot gP = pgP$. This gives a homomorphism $G\to S(G/P)=S_r$, which is clearly not identically equal to $1$. Since $G$ is simple, the kernel is thus trivial and hence $S_r$ contains an isomorphic copy of $G$ as a subgroup. So $p^m r| r!$.

Comment: But hmm i don't understand why $G/P$ has a group structure since $P$ is not normal in $G$ otherwise $G$ would not be simple. ? Am i confused?

Comment: I don't need a group structure, it's just a set being acted on. Its members are the left cosets $gP$, $g\in G$, and there are $[G:P]=r$ of these.

Comment: Yep i was guessing that was it!! thank u again!